# why cassandra cluster write is ok but update always fail (about 30%)?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm working with Cassandra Cluster with 4 nodes (Amazon), I have test_ks_r2 with replication factor = 2, write and update with consistency level = ALL, read with consistency level = ONE. The code are using datastax java driver (version 2.1.5):

```
    // schema of user column family
    CREATE TABLE user (
        id text PRIMARY KEY,
        password text,
        username text
    );


    // ResultSet class
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class ResultSet {
      private List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
      private Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

      public void setIdList(List<String> v) {idList = v;}
      public List<String> getIdList() { return idList;}

      public void setData(Map<String, List<String>> v) {data = v;}
      public Map<String, List<String>> getData() {return data;}
    }

    // test cassandra class
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import com.datastax.driver.core.*;
    import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Builder;
    import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder;

    class TestCassandra {
        private ConsistencyLevel getConsistencyLevel(String consistency) {
          System.out.println("consistency level string: " + consistency);
          if(consistency.equals("one")) {
              System.out.println("using consistency level: ONE");
              return ConsistencyLevel.ONE;
          }
          else if(consistency.equals("two")) {
              System.out.println("using consistency level: TWO");
              return ConsistencyLevel.TWO;
          }
          else if(consistency.equals("quorum")) {
              System.out.println("using consistency level: QUORUM");
              return ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM;
          }
          else if(consistency.equals("all")) {
              System.out.println("using consistency level: ALL");
              return ConsistencyLevel.ALL;
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("using default consistency level: ONE");
              return ConsistencyLevel.ONE;
          }
      }

      public void testWriteUpdateRead(int n, String mode, int delay) {
          if (mode.equals("QueryBuilder")) {                
              System.out.println("test write & read with QueryBuilder ...");    
          } else if (mode.equals("PreparedStatement")) {
              System.out.println("test write & read with PreparedStatement ...");
          } else {
              System.exit(-1);
          }

          ResultSet resultSet = write(n, mode, getConsistencyLevel("all")); 
          read(resultSet.getIdList(), resultSet.getData(), getConsistencyLevel("one"));
          // update data
          update(resultSet, mode, getConsistencyLevel("all"), delay);
          // read again
          read(resultSet.getIdList(), resultSet.getData(), getConsistencyLevel("one"));
      }  

      public ResultSet update(ResultSet resultSet, String mode, ConsistencyLevel consistencyLevel, int delay) {
          PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE id = ?")
                                  .setConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel);
          List<String> idList = resultSet.getIdList();
          Map<String, List<String>> data = resultSet.getData();

          for (String idRead: idList) {
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(delay);
              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                  System.out.println(e);
              }
              String newPassword = "new password" + idRead;

              if (mode.equals("QueryBuilder")) {
                  session.execute(
                              QueryBuilder.update("user")
                                  .where(QueryBuilder.eq("id", idRead))
                                  .with(QueryBuilder.set("password", newPassword))
                                  .setConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel)
                          );

              } else  {
                  ResultSet result = session.execute(ps.bind(newPassword, idRead));
                  System.out.println(result);
              }

              List<String> itemValues = new ArrayList<String>();
              itemValues.add("empty");
              itemValues.add(newPassword);
              data.put(idRead, itemValues);
          }

          System.out.println("Update " + Objects.toString(idList.size(), null) + " times");
          resultSet.setData(data);
          return resultSet;
      }    

      public ResultSet write(int n, String mode, ConsistencyLevel consistencyLevel) {
          PreparedStatement ps = session
                                  .prepare("INSERT INTO user (id, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
                                  .setConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel);

          String idWrite = "";                        
          List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
          Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

          for (int i=0; i<n;i++) {
              idWrite =  Objects.toString(System.currentTimeMillis(),null);
              String username = "username" + idWrite;
              String password = "password" + idWrite;



              List<String> itemValues = new ArrayList<String>();
              itemValues.add(username);
              itemValues.add(password);

              if (mode.equals("QueryBuilder")) {
                  session.execute(
                              QueryBuilder.insertInto("user")
                                  .value("id", idWrite)
                                  .value("username", username)
                                  .value("password", password)
                                  .setConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel)
                              );

              } else  {
                  session.execute(ps.bind(idWrite, username, password));
              }   
              idList.add(idWrite);
              data.put(idWrite, itemValues);
          }

          ResultSet resultSet = new ResultSet();
          resultSet.setIdList(idList);
          resultSet.setData(data);

          System.out.println("Write " + Objects.toString(n, null) + " times");
          return resultSet;
      }   

      public void read(List<String> idList, Map<String, List<String>> data, ConsistencyLevel consistencyLevel) {
          int readCount;
          int success = 0;
          for (String idRead: idList) {
              PreparedStatement stmt = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?").setConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel);
              List<String> itemValues = data.get(idRead);
              try {
                  readCount = 0;
                  Row resultRow = null; 
                  for (Row row : session.execute(stmt.bind(idRead))) {
                      readCount++;
                      resultRow = row;
                  }

                  // there should be only 1 read, in such case, this is a successful read of a recent write
                  if (readCount==1) {
                      if(itemValues.get(1).equals(resultRow.getString("password"))) {
                          success++;    
                      } else {
                          System.out.println("password: " + itemValues.get(1));
                          System.out.println("password in database: " + resultRow.getString("password"));
                      }
                  }

              } catch (Exception e) {
                  success = success + 0;  // do not increase success since there is an exception
              }
          }


          System.out.println("Successfully read back " + Objects.toString(success, null) + " times");
      } 
    }
```

### Here is my result

```
    Write 40 times
    consistency level string: one
    using consistency level: ONE
    Successfully read back 40 times
    consistency level string: all
    using consistency level: ALL
    Update 40 times
    consistency level string: one
    using consistency level: ONE
    Successfully read back 32 times
```

Update always fail about ~ 30%. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You said you are using consistency level ALL for updates but your result says you're using one. In that case you might have inconsistencies if you're doing them right after the other. I would suggest using QUORUM. Though you should run into the same kind of issue.

Comment: @Popinou: I only use consistency ONE for read, update and write are using consistency level ALL. consistency level print before print result of action

Comment: Your `read()` methods swallows exceptions silently, could you add a log in the catch block?

Comment: have you solved it?  I have the same issue even using QUORUM, I hade 5 nodes in cluster